# How do I access variables in this JSON return using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

How do I access the returned JSON Data? e.g the name array?  to work

JSON...

```
{"COLUMNS":["NAME"],"DATA":[["Item 1"],["Item 2"]]}
```

The data.NAME[1] doesn't seem to have any data in it..

```
 $.getJSON('url/json.php',
     function(data){
    $('#debug').html('data:' + data.NAME[1]);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing your JSON string

```
{"COLUMNS":["NAME"],"DATA":[["Item 1"],["Item 2"]]}
```

will return a javascript object like:

```
var data = {
    COLUMNS: ["NAME"],
    DATA: [["Item 1"], ["Item 2"]]   
}
```

so there is no identifier for `data.NAME[1]`.

You may access `data.COLUMNS[0]` returning `"NAME"` or `data.DATA[0][0]` returning `"Item 1"`.

Comment: +1 nice answer. You probably meant `data.DATA[0][0]` there. Weird JSON structure.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're *trying* to access.
`data.COLUMNS[0]` should get you `"NAME"`.
`data.DATA[0]` should get you the `["Item 1"]` array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using aspx make sure that you check data.d not data. (this was a recent change?)

Comment: its from coldfusion actually, SeralizeJSON function...oddness